# CIFAR-10 python architicture

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-cnn-from-scratch-for-cifar-10-photo-classification/).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I am trying to understand the given code which uses the CIFAR-10 dataset.

- why is he using `kernel_initializer='he_uniform'?`
- why did he choose the 128 for the dense layer?
- what will happen if we add more dense layer to the code like:
  `model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))`
- is there any way to increase the accuracy of the model?
- what would be a suitable dropout rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is he using `kernel_initializer='he_uniform'`?

The weights in a layer of a neural network are initialized randomly. How though? Which distribution should they follow? `he_uniform` is a strategy for initializing the weights of that layer.

> why did he choose the 128 for the dense layer?

This was chosen arbitrarily.

> What will happen if we add more dense layer to the code like:
> `model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))`

I assime you mean to add them where the other 128-neuron Dense layer is (there it won't break the model) The model will become deeper and have a **much higher** number of parameters (i.e. your model will become more complex) with whatever positives or negatives come along with this.

> what would be a suitable dropout rate?

Usually you see rates in the range of [0.2, 0.5]. Higher rates reduce overfitting but might cause training to become more unstable.